# How to deal with potential null value in a sort_by?

Tags: jmespath

I have an array of objects like so:

```json
{
    "openingDates": [
        {
            "location": "Main St.",
            "openingDate": "2023-01-09T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "location": "Northwood Park",
            "openingDate": "2006-01-10T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an expression to sort by openingDate then get the openingDate value:

```
sort_by(openingDates, &openingDate)[0].openingDate
```

However, `openingDates` can potentially be `null`, which will obviously cause an error if I try to run a sort on it. Is there a way to prevent the sort in my expression if the value is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from the fact that `sort_by` will only accept the first parameter to be an array.

This say, the [`to_array`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array) function can help you do an array of your null value, as `to_array(null)` will give you `[null]`.
And, with an array containing null, your further query would return you a `null` for the `openingDate`, as expected.

So, given

```json
{}
```

And the query

```
sort_by(to_array(openingDates), &openingDate)[0].openingDate
```

This will yield

```json
null
```

And will still give

```json
"2006-01-10T00:00:00Z"
```

On your example object.

Comment: Yes I tested the expression on the jmespath.org website and it looks like it is valid. Would the case be the same when running it in something like Java code? Looks like I get an error:

`io.burt.jmespath.function.ArgumentTypeException: Invalid argument type calling "sort_by": expected array of object but was null`

Comment: I tested with the Python implementation, it should do for the others, but let me have a look, at the Java one, then.

Comment: Did you look at this chapter of the project, though: https://github.com/burtcorp/jmespath-java#configuration

Comment: This jmespath java configuration doc is exactly what I needed!